# setOnClickListener shows error

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

First of all, please don't mark it a duplicate. I found similar question on `stackoverflow.com` but I could not find my solution. Please look at this image
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOZYw.jpg)

I am trying to check that EditText should not be empty. But the `setOnClickListener` is displayed in red. I tried solutions suggested in other similar questions and mentioned `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` but still it is not working.

So, any help that could help me solve the problem from anyone is really appreciated.

This is the java file

```
package com.example.rtrjs.abc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign up");
}
EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfn);
Button buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.breg);
buton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener())
}
```

When it showed error I didnot proceed further.

Comment: You should be calling setOnClickListener from your onCreate method, are not inside of the onCreate method from the screenshot you provided.

Answer (score 2):

First you are not inside any method, so you will not be able to assign the listener, second you are missing the onClick method inside de OnClickListener. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do your stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not in the onCreate() method

EDIT :

Try this way :

```
package com.example.rtrjs.abc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign up");
        EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfn);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.breg);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //process
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Also I suggest you to use the string.xml file for your "Sign up" in order to be prepared for multi language support ;)

Comment: could you please help me with the sample code @ShellCode

Comment: If you want code, provide us code, not just a screenshot ;) But you just have to put the 3 lines of code before the }

Comment: I am sorry wait I will edit my question and add the code

Comment: It is still the same

Comment: Under android studio there is a magic command which is ALT+ENTER it will propose you multiple solutions, you can try one

Comment: If I press `Alt+Enter` it shows "Insert app Indexing API code"

Comment: Do it, it's probably because you didn't choose a min API level for your project

Comment: I chose it's API 16 for Jellybean

Comment: Well I don't know... the code is correct, it's probably an issue with your project's config

Comment: Alright thanks for your effort. I really appreciate it. Please comment or reply to this question if you ever happen to get a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this:

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign up");
        EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfn);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.breg);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // logic here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the `setOnClickListener` in `button.setOnClickListener` is still displayed in red. I tried everything. All syntax is correct. All packages are imported.

Comment: My original answer was missing a semi-colon which could have been causing the red unline to display (hovering over would have told you what the issue was). Go ahead and try now.

Comment: If I press `Alt+Enter` it shows `Insert app Indexing API code`

And my syntax is correct but still, it is displayed in red.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the `OnClickListener` function code for your `Button` and `EditText` in the `OnCreate` method like this

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign up");
        EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etfn);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.breg);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //process
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Bhai @AnujSehgal yahi to kiya hai. Sab yahi bata rahe hain. Par `button.setOnClickListener` me error hai. Package use kiya, syntax sahi hai phir bhi error hai. Samajh nahi aata kya karun.

Comment: Go to "Build --> Clean Project" then again "Build --> Rebuild project" and please update all the dependencies in build.gradle(Module:App) according to compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion.